# C#: Have a class method return itself

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm editing a piece of code where there are two separate classes Application and LogIn.

```
public class Application: WebEntity
{
    public void logInMethod()
    {
        LogIn logInObject = new LogIn();
        this = logInObject.logUserIn("user", "password");
    }
}
```

Since logging in is a feature of the Application, I want to create a method that uses LogIn. The logIn.logUserIn("user", "password") currently return an object of Application. I want to be able to do something like whats done on step 6 (above). Is this possible?

Comment: No, you can't reassign the "this" pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't.

A method can't set the instance it's executing on. It's hard to understand what you want to do, but what you might want to do, is create a method that returns an instance of `Application` :

```
public class Application : WebEntity
{
    public static Application CreateLogedInApplication()
    {
        LogIn logInObject = new LogIn();
        Application newApplication = logInObject.logUserIn("user", "password");

        return newApplication;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I believe I need to do is redesign logUserIn to not return an object of Application, and just have any Application variables set in the method logUserIn to be moved into the Application class.
With my question I was trying to see if there is an easier way to this

Comment: It's hard to give advice on how to structure your application with so little information, but I get the feeling you should concentrate on [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for the time being. For example, having an application that doesn't know how to login itself, but has an instance of a class that does know how (`LogIn`) would be something reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like this:

```
public class Application
{
    private Token _token = null;

    public void logInMethod()
    {
        LogIn logInObject = new LogIn();
        _token = logInObject.logUserIn("user", "password");
    }
}

public abstract class Token
{
    public abstract string UserName { get; }
    public abstract bool Validated { get; }
}

public class LogIn
{
    private class TokenImpl : Token
    {
        public TokenImpl(string userName, bool validated)
        {
            _userName = userName;
            _validated = validated;
        }
        private string _userName;
        private bool _validated;
        public override string UserName { get { return _userName; } }
        public override bool Validated { get { return _validated; } }
    }

    public Token logUserIn(string userName, string password)
    {
        return new TokenImpl(userName, password == "pAssw0rd");
    }
}
```

Basically the `LogIn` class creates a `Token` that the `Application` class can use.